# How to achive no selection in jelly <f:select/>?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

In config.jelly, I have:

```
<f:entry field="field1">
   <f:select/>
</f:entry>
```

And corresponding java code that fills above components with value:

```
public ListBoxModel doFillField1Items() {
        ...
}
```

When the user enters the config page, field `field1` is filled with the first value provided by method `doFillField1Items()`.

And my question:
Is it a way to configure(either in jelly or java) this `<f:select/>` component to have initially no selection for field `field1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HTML point of view there is no such thing as "no selection". `<select>` tag if has any `<option>` available then will be selected. Only way that "nothing is selected" is to remove all options from it.

I don't know Jelly but you probably want to achieve code like this:

`<select required>
  <option selected disabled value="">No option selected</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>`

Code above will tell browser to pre-select option "No option selected", but because it's disabled, then after changing selection user will not be able to choose back "No option selected". Combined `required` attribute added to `<select>` and `<option value="">` will force user to make a selection (in theory) because otherwise `<form>` (assuming that you have one) will be ivalid.